# Multiple mount events on mounting iPod

Tags: linux, ipod, gio

I am working on an app which has to detect if a storage volume is mounted or unmounted. I am using `GIO` for that. I listening for the `mount-added` and `mount-removed` signals. Everything works fine when I mount/unmount a pen drive. However, I am seeing an issue when mounting an iPod. I am getting two callbacks each on mount and unmount. I assumed one of the `GMount` objects would be [shadowed](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gio/unstable/GMount.html#g-mount-is-shadowed) but [g_mount_is_shadowed](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gio/unstable/GMount.html#g-mount-is-shadowed) is returning false for both. How do I decide which one to process and which to ignore? I cannot process both. I have to detect the mount/unmount corresponding to the storage device and process only that.

```
int main()
{
    g_type_init();
    GVolumeMonitor* volume_monitor = g_volume_monitor_get();
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(volume_monitor), "mount-added", G_CALLBACK(mount_added), NULL);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(volume_monitor), "mount-removed", G_CALLBACK(mount_removed), NULL);

    GMainLoop* main_loop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);        
    g_main_loop_run(main_loop);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Did you try `volume-added` and `volume-removed` ?

Comment: I did. And I saw that I get only 1 one callback. But I am not sure I that will all my use cases (I want to be able to detect addition/removal of all *storage* devices) and I would like to stick with the `mount-xxx` signals if only to avoid extensive test cases.

Comment: All storage devices are volumes on Linux, did you actually try one?

Comment: Ismail: That sounds like there is at least one OS where this is not the case. Which would that be, and why so?

Comment: @user562374 We are talking about Linux here.

Comment: @Ismail: As I mentioned earlier, I tried a CDROM and the iPod. I still have some confusion over differences between mount points and volumes. I guess it will be better to ask that in a separate question. I am not even sure if SO is the right place to ask that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. `GIO` emits a `mount-added` signal for each filesystem that is added. The iPod has two file systems - one for the OS and one for storing music. Hence the repeated callback. The same happens on unmount. This has nothing to do with shadowed mounts. Unfortunately, I still don't know how to distinguish between the two mounts. The only difference `GIO`shows is that one of the `GMount` objects does not have a `GVolume` object associated with it. I don't know how to interpret that.